# Disable Automatic Updates for Adobe CS4 on Windows 7

Tags: adobe-creative-suite

I want to disable Automatic Updates for  Adobe Creative Suite CS4 on Windows 7. I followed the steps as given in [here](http://www.jeffreysward.com/editorials/daaucs4.htm).

```
1. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\
2. Set "AdobeOnlineDefault" to "0" (zero). If it doesnt exist, create it as a new String Value.
3. Go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\CSXSPreferences\
4. Set "UpdatesAllowed" to "0" (zero). If it doesnt exist, create it as a new String Value.
```

I checked my Windows registry. There was no AdobeOnlineDefault in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Adobe\

However the following was successful. But still the updater pops-up.

```
To Change the Adobe Updater preferences, do the following:

1. Start the AdobeUpdater.exe application from ...\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Updater 6
2. When the update screen appears, click the Preferences button
3. Uncheck the Automatically Check for updates checkbox and click OK
```

[Adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/408/kb408711.html) own kb says the following , but I'm not sure if this works in Windows 7.

```
On Windows XP or Windows Vista

   1. Using Regedit.exe, navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Adobe
   2. Create a new key in this folder named "Updater"
   3. Create a new DWORD value within this key named "Enterprise with a value of "1"
```

Another [tutorial](http://garmahis.com/tips/how-to-disable-adobe-updater/) says to change the AdobeUpdaterPrefs.dat file which in my case is here : C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Adobe\Updater6\AdobeUpdaterPrefs.dat , but I do not know how to edit this xml file. Is there a proper way to disable Automatic Updates for  Adobe CS4 ?

Comment: Might be a silly suggestion but would removing the services and startup from `msconfig` cover your needs?

Comment: it doesn't..there's some way it re-spawns every couple of weeks

Comment: Have you tried the reg keys provided under [kb404813](http://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/kb/disable-access-cs4-service-extensions.html) it's the parent to the kb you referenced, Under title **Sample plist files and registry keys**